# how to edit product details page html in magento adminhtml

Tags: magento

I want to solve an issue in :

how to edit product details page html in magento adminhtml

I want to insert the product id (non editable) value in product information --> General tab --> just above name.

I have searched my magento adminhtml core code, phtml and searched in google but didn't find how to add entity id above name. I am so tired after searching more than 15 files here to find.

I will be very much please if someone help me and i will do the work. Thanks all.
[image: add product id]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can turn on template path hints for the backend by editing:

```
app/code/core/Mage/Core/etc/system.xml
```

Near line 483 is the definition for template path hints, set the following:

```
<show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
```

Then turn on hints in your backend and reload the backend page.

The file is:

```
app/default/adminhtml/default/default/template/widget/form/renderer/fieldset.phtml
```

If you follow the rabbit hole, you'll eventually end up at:

```
app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/catalog/product/edit.phtml
```

You could drop something into the top of the form there, since the rest of the form is built with javascript and the rabbit hole keeps going. Of course, you will probably want to do this the correct way by doing it in a module, but for quick and dirty, there ya go.

Comment: Can you please describe the term *rabbit hole* and how can i edit it.

Comment: @Md.AbdullahAlMamun You, sir, win all of the internets forever.

Comment: From wikipedia: "down the rabbit hole", a metaphor for adventure into the (potentially weird) unknown, from its use in Alice's Adventures in Wonderland